# LED with lower Rth heats more than others

Tags: led, thermal, efficiency

On my IMS PCB I mounted three types of LEDs:

https://dammedia.osram.info/media/resource/hires/osram-dam-8405100/GD%20QSSPA1.14_EN.pdf

https://dammedia.osram.info/media/resource/hires/osram-dam-14186580/GH%20QSSPA1.24_EN.pdf

https://dammedia.osram.info/media/resource/hires/osram-dam-8405096/GW%20QSSPA1.EM_EN.pdf

They all share the same footprint (unless a different pinout) and I followed the recommended solder pad.

All the LEDs are driven by the same circuit based on [ILD8150](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-ILD8150_ILD8150E-DataSheet-v01_04-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462696dbf120169ba96613f4c20). During the test I set the same current for all of them: 350 mA with 50% PWM.

The white and red LEDs are almost cold, while the blue ones become too hot to touch in a couple of seconds. I'm talking about the case itself.

Looking at the datasheets I read:

- red (GH) RthJS = 4.2 K/W with ηe = 47 %
- white (FW) RthJS = 5.4 K/W with ηe = 40 %
- **blue (GD) RthJS = 2.9 K/W with ηe = 68 %**

The blue LEDs are the most efficient (68%) and thus the ones with the lower RthJS because they convert electrical energy to light energy better than the others.

**So why they almost burn with such a low current (50 %) while the others are cold?**

I'm going to exclude a soldering issue because it happens with all of them.
Did I miss any other important parameter?

Here is the schematic of the PCB:

[image]

To exclude any issue with the driver too, I powered the LEDs with a constant-current power supply, and the behavior is the same.

Here the driver schematic, but as I stated the issues it still there also WITHOUT the driver:

[image]

I'm sure I cannot explain it well. So I simplify it.
This test circuit leads to the described issue:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZVr7P.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If D1 is white or red the LED is cold.
If D1 is blue (above there are the datasheets) the LED burns.

With the setup above, that means:

- programmable power supply with limiting current set to 160 mA
- NO DRIVER, just connected the power supply to each string of LEDs (one per time, of course)

I get the following results:

**RED string**

- Measured current (with multimeter in series): 160.8 mA
- Measured forward voltage for each LED: 1930 mV ± 5 mV (as expected)
- Temperature of the case: cool
- Temperature of the PCB: cool

**WHITE string**

- Measured current (with multimeter in series): 160.2 mA
- Measured forward voltage for each LED: 2780 mV ± 7 mV (as expected)
- Temperature of the case: cool
- Temperature of the PCB: cool

**BLUE string**

- Measured current (with multimeter in series): 161.0 mA
- Measured forward voltage for each LED: 2775 mV ± 6 mV (as expected)
- Temperature of the case: hot
- Temperature of the PCB: cool

It's not true there is no heatsink: the IMS PCB offer by itself a quite good surface and thermal conductivity for such a short tests. In fact, if I power on even a red or white LED on the desk (not soldered to the IMS PCB) it becomes hot as well.

Here is the PCB without LEDs:

[image]

Here is the PCB with LEDs:

[image]

Comment: That’s certainly strange. How’s heatsinking, identical for all three types?

Comment: @winny, for testing purpose there is no heatsink right now but the IMS PCB. All the footprints are identical. It's the case of the blue LED that heats up, not the PCB below.

Comment: Here it is, but I said the weird behavior is the same also WITHOUT the driver. Anyway I followed your hint and added the driver schematic.

Comment: @Andyaka, sorry but this is the real schematics. The HS and LS are the high-side (anode) and low-side (cathode) of each section. So say, HS of the red-driver goes to J1 pin 4 and LS to J1 pin 1. HS of blue driver goes to J1 pin 6 and LS to J1 pin 5, etc...

Comment: I don't have a schematic with these connections because there are wires between them. Anyway, if I connect a power supply (constant current) between anode and cathode of the LED series the behavior is the same. Sorry but I'm not able to explain it better: the driver changes nothing for my issue.

Comment: What do you mean the "red-driver" - you said they are driven by the same circuit.

Comment: Please read what I've written. As you can see there are THREE series of LED. Each one is driven by the same driver, by the same circuit. Of course there is one driver of each series, but they are identical! They are not different.

Comment: I apologize, but why we're talking about the driver if the issue is NOT related to it? Putting a power supply to each LED series (with the SAME current) is enough to raise the issue.

Comment: Go back to your bench supply setup. Drive all 3 LED strings. Measure the voltage across an LED in each string. Are they what you expect? I ask because, at a nominal 160 mA, your "cool" LEDs should not be cool. Your whites, for instance, should be dissipating about 1/2 watt per LED, or 3W per string, and without a heat sink should be getting toasty. The issue, as I see it, is not, "Why are the blues getting hot?", but rather, "Why aren't the others getting hot?"

Comment: What’s the acceptable Vf range for the driver? Can it regulate the current with only two blue LEDs? Bad batch of IHS<->blue LEDs? Resolver then yourself?

Comment: If the LED heats up but the IHS does not, again, resolder the LED to the IHS.

Comment: I would suspect that your constant current power supply isn't as constant as you think it is.  The string with only 2 LEDs may be getting more current than they should.  Check what the current really is through each string.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, question updated with the measures you asked for.

Comment: You're putting the same amount of energy in, the white LEDs are generating more heat (due to the phosphor), but the lower dissipation parts feel hotter.  If you haven't made a measurement error, then less heat is leaving the hotter part.  Post a picture of your soldering job as well as a blank board with no LEDs on it.  Are you using identical boards for both LEDs?

Comment: @user1850479, question updated. The PCB hosts all the three types of LEDs and the footprints are identical.

Comment: I would double check that the central thermal pad is making good contact (can't really see any soldering in the picture).  My guess is it didn't reflow properly.  FWIW, the thermal design on that board should work for low power loads like this, but isn't ideal since you don't have a lot of copper area for heat to diffuse through the insulating dielectric layer to the conductive aluminum layer below.

Comment: You have two blue LEDs. Are they both hot the same amount? Is a blue LED giving the same heat as the others off-pcb (on desktop)? Is there any way there is a short-circuit below the blue LED?

Comment: @Mark - OK, so the blue and the whites are dissipating almost exactly the same amount of power, but one is running hot and the other is not. It's pretty clear that your blues are not making nearly as good thermal contact with the PCB as the whites are. I have no idea why. If anything, the data sheet says the whites should experience just about twice the temperature rise as the blues. So clearly something is wrong with your mounting.

Comment: @user1850479, I'm not sure how to check the soldering. Of course I can try to mount other PCBs. It's weird that only the blue LEDs (all of them) have this behavior, while all the others (and there are many more) are *all* cool.

Comment: @user1850479, yes about the copper areas I asked a separate question (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/574909/copper-areas-on-ims-pcb) and on the next revision of the PCB I'm going to increase the copper near the LEDs.

Comment: Do you have a hot air station? Try reflowing one of the hot LEDs and see if temperature improves. If not, take it off and check if there is solder on all three LED terminals. Finally, if everything looks good, try another batch of LEDs in case you got some with a defective pad. Rare but it can happen or they can be damaged during reflow.

Comment: @user1850479 update: I received some boards mounted by a PCB house (with P&P and reflow) and the behavior is exactly the same. I also added more copper area, but nothing has changed.